# ProLiant G7 - back USB ports two controllers or one?

Tags: usb

I have a HP ProLiant DL380 G7.  On the back of it are two USB ports side by side.  Do these share a single controller?

Comment: Why do you ask? What's the _real_ question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to `lsusb` on an HP ProLiant DL380 G7, there are two PCI devices serving as USB controllers:

```
# lspci | grep -i usb
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1
02:00.4 USB controller: Hewlett-Packard Company Integrated Lights-Out Standard Virtual USB Controller (rev 01)
```

Note that there are two PCI devices involved: 00:1d and 02:00. .0, .1, .2, etc are all subdevices/functions of a given PCI device.

02:00 is a virtual device provided by the ILO for things like remote console and remote media.

That leaves 00:1d as the only physical USB controller in the system. So not only are the two USB ports on the back from the same controller, but they share a controller with the ports on the front of the system as well.

Comment: Thanks for looking. Now I'd like to know what the OP actually wants to know :)

Comment: @ewwhite - I asked what I wanted to know.  And Michael gave an excellent answer.

Comment: @horsehair Can you give some context on why you care about the USB bus distribution?

Comment: @ewwhite - I'm interested because I have high-speed devices that I need to distribute evenly over controllers, not ports.

Comment: You know these are USB 2.0, right?

Comment: @ewwhite - my devices are also constrained to usb 2.0

Comment: Sounds like you're going to want to install a couple USB expansion cards. At least they're cheap, and the DL380 has plenty of room for them. Used to pick them up for something like $5/pc.

Comment: Incidentally, the "distribute devices across controllers" is good context that belonged in the original question.

Answer (score 5):

From my perspective, I think it's a single controller installed to the server. In order to get the confirmation, I would suggest you check the proper motherboard specifications.